# Catch MouseWheel/Scroll event on child controll in design-time C#

Tags: c#, scrollbar, design-time, panels

I is there a way to catch MouseWheel/Scroll event on panel, inside another panel while whole window is in design-time ?

Scrollbar works on parent, but only when I hover its area by mouse. When inner controll is hovered, no scroll event is execuded.

To get what I mean: 
1) Create empty WindowsForms project
2) Place into form Panel (call it PanelA)
3) Change color of PanelA
3) Enable AutoScroll for PanelA
4) Place into PanelA new Panel (call it PanelB)
5) Make PanelB highter than PanelA
6) Change PanelB color
You will get something like:
[image]

Now, when you put your mouse on scrollbar, you can scroll red panel, but if mouse is inside PanelA, no scroll event is execuded. 
If you build that form, everything works, but I want to scroll that content in design-time, not run-time. 
Thanks in advice for help

Comment: Pretty much the universal mouse wheel question, lots and lots of existing Q+A about it.  Older versions of Windows (before 10) send the mouse wheel message to the control that has the focus.  So hovering is not helpful.  And the panel must have a control that can get the focus.  Since the control itself is rarely interested in the wheel message, it gets passed to the parent.  The panel likes it.

Comment: Okey, but I have that problem only in design-time, when controll is builded and execuded in run-time, everything works as it should. I must missing something which disallow me to do it in design-time

Comment: You certainly missed something, you gave the worst possible description of your problem.

Comment: I edited my question to show more info what I mean